How to test my Wrapped token/Stablecoin in a testnet?
Is it possible to test if my wrapped token or stablecoin peg system is working in some testnet? Or I need to deploy it in the mainnet?

Yes, it’s possible to test your wrapped token or stablecoin peg system on a testnet before deploying it on the mainnet.
You can do that by simply deploying the corresponding token contract to your desired testnet, and then test all the functionalities, allowing you to experiment and identify any issues without risking real assets.
Here’s an example of USDC (i.e., a stablecoin) token contract on Sepolia Testnet:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0x1c7d4b196cb0c7b01d743fbc6116a902379c7238#code
Here’s an example of wETH (i.e., a wrapped token) token contract on Sepolia Testnet:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0xfff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b14#code

Thank you! Btw is not possible to test if the price keeps pegged, right? as Testnet tokens doesn't have price

For implementing the price conversion, you can use Chainlink Price Feeds, that are available on various popular test networks, like Sepolia, Avalanche-Fuji, etc.
